# How to translate wordpress backend to another language

Tags: plugin-development, multi-language, translation, language

Is there any way to translate wordpress entire backend to another language that is not supported yet. ? I mean, my language is Sinhala (Sri Lanka) and sinhala is not yet included by default on Wordpress. But I'm looking for creating a plugin or something to translate backend to Sinhala.

So, could anybody please tell me what is the proper and formal way of doing it... ?

Thanks..

Comment: try to follow the links here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Translating_With_GlotPress

Comment: @Mark Thanks, but what I'm looking for is translate the interface with a plugin. So, when the user wants the interface in Sinhala, he can install and activate the plugin.

Comment: so do you want to translate, or you have a translation that you want to be activated with a plugin, or both?

Comment: I think 2nd option is the one I'm looking for. Is that possible ?

Comment: @Tharindulucky There's already a plugin called WPML http://wpml.org/ which allows you to translate Wordpress itself as well as Themes, Plugins, etc. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, a Sinhala translation is already in progress.

https://si.wordpress.org/  http://wpcentral.io/internationalization/si/

Maybe it would be a good idea to join that team.

First, you need to create .po files for the Sinhala translation of WordPress.  You're going to need four of these files. They will be called

```
si_LK.po
admin-si_LK.po
admin-network-si_LK.po
continents-cities-si_LK.po
```

If all you want to do is translate the back end, you only need to provide `admin-si_LK.po`.  If you already have some or all these files, great.

Second, you need to generate the corresponding .mo files by compiling the .po files. You can do this by using Glotpress.  https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/tools/glotpress-translate-wordpress-org/

Third, you need to put them into the following directory in your test WordPress installation. Then you can test and edit.

```
.../wp-content/languages/
```

Finally, you can contribute your translation back to the WordPress core via Glotpress.

As of WordPress 4.0, you wouldn't use a plugin to provide a translation. Instead, you'd contribute your translation directly to the WordPress code base,